# How do you wrap components with mxml?

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to wrap some text with a component but can not figure out how to align them correctly. Here is what I am looking for:

If you have not entered your credentials, enter your credentials by 
clicking *Set Credentials*.

The "If you have not entered your credentials, enter your credentials by clicking" is a string.

The "Set Credentials" is a button so it can be clicked by the user.

I tried putting the string in a textarea which wrapped the text but could not get the button to horizontally align with the text.  I also tried adding them both with Tile, then I do not get proper wrapping.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think messing with the baseline property can fix that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<mx:Text width="100%">
 <mx:htmlText><![CDATA[
      If you have not entered your credentials, enter your credentials by clicking 
      <a href='<Your hyperlink>' target='_blank'>Set Credentials.</a>
   ]]>
 </mx:htmlText>
</mx:Text>
```

Comment: This is the first thing I originally tried but my hyperlink needs to be a function. That is why I have a link button I created. That buttons click event calls a function to handle the click.  Also, the text needs to be localized so I pull that text from a properties file that I store in a var and could not figure out how to have that var ex: {_pageText} display in the cdata.

Comment: Example:
<mx:Text width="100%">
 <mx:htmlText><![CDATA[
      {_pageText} 
      <a href='<Your hyperlink>' target='_blank'> _buttonText</a>
   ]]>
 </mx:htmlText>
</mx:Text>

Comment: Did you try using resourceManager.getString("<property file name>", "<property name>"). Well obviously you would want to define the resource bundle using:  <mx:Metadata> [ResourceBundle("resources")] </mx:Metadata>

Comment: Yes, I have no issues getting the value from the property file to the var. I just have the issue of displaying the var in the htmlText.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the baseline property to align several controls correctly : http://butterfliesandbugs.wordpress.com/2008/02/25/baseline-alignment-with-constraints-in-flex-3/